# Flutter and Dart Login issues - Too many requests error

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I try to display the error messages when the user is logging using this try-catch block:

```
try {               
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: email,
                  password: password,
                );

                Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  notesRoute,
                  (route) => false,
                );
              } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                devtools.log(e.code);
                await showErrorDialog(
                  context,
                  "Error: ${e.code}",
                );
              } catch (e) {
                devtools.log(e.toString());
                await showErrorDialog(
                  context,
                  "Error: ${e.toString()}",
                );
              }
            }
```

But what happens is the error is displayed and then when I click "ok", and re-enter with the correct credentials it says "too many requests," even though I just clicked the login button once.

Here is the code block for the showErrorDialog function:

```
Future<void> showErrorDialog(
  BuildContext context,
  String text,
) {
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("An error occured here!"),
          content: Text(text),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text("Ok"),
            )
          ],
        );
      });
}
```

Kindly help!

I tried hot restarting my main dart file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at the docs [Error Handling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/errors)

> Other errors such as too-many-requests or operation-not-allowed may be thrown if you reach the Firebase Authentication quota, or have not enabled a specific auth provider.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know the issue automatically got resolve when I tried debugging the file (after changing the sign in quota per hour to 1000 from a 100.